# Is it possible to use rsync inside of iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, rsync

is it possible to use rsync lib inside of an iPhone or iPad app? Or maybe there are any alternatives suitable for remote file sync over sftp?

Comment: What is it you want? Sync a remote folder to the application documents folder? In any case, no, you can't use rsync cause you can't run command line commands. And there's no framework in the iOS SDK to do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to close this question because at the moment there are only few possible solutions and neither of them runs 'out of the box'.

I have found several programs on the AppSote which somehow mimics rsync functionality so after all using rsync is possible, however not so simple as it seems.

Modifiying rsync to turn it into a library is feasible, but this is not how author of one of these programs did it. Doing so would subject app to GPL, which not permitted by Apple.

There are other approaches, such as http://search.cpan.org/~leakin/File-Rsync-0.42/Rsync.pm (a perl module), and https://github.com/kolosy/rsync.net (c#).

I doubt someone would really need rsync lib for iphone since iOS 5.0 was released. However one may need it to support some legacy code, but even then rewriting rsync lib from scratch is questionable, because it is complex tool and this task certainly will take more than two or three month.

Comment: Hi Dig. Interesting read. What is it about iOS 5 that means you don't need Rsync? Are you talking about iCloud?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Maybe I was too categorical about rsync – I was thinking about project, which my client wanted to lauch 6 month ago - file sharing app for iOS devices.

Comment: @dig Hi, did you eventually resort to using iCloud or rsync? If it was iCloud, did it work for you? I have heard bad stories about using it especially along with CoreData.

Comment: @Unheilig Hi, I used simple restful server for that task, maybe better tools appeared since that time.

Answer (score 5):

Acrosync library is a good choice, and I have made a demo for it.
It is licensed under the RPL license, and commercial license are provided.

Repository:
https://github.com/gilbertchen/acrosync-library

My demo (fixed some bugs):
https://github.com/Lessica/Acrosync-Demo

Answer (score 2):

acrosync seems to be worth checking out as it implements a rsync client library rewritten from scratch and is available on multiple platforms, including iOS.

https://acrosync.com/library.html

Comment: Thank you for pointing this interesting tool, I wish I had it 3 years ago :-)