# How can I update a file incrementally in iOS. (File patching)

Tags: ios, dynamic, versioning

I have a huge text file in my application (version 1.0).

Lets assume that a new version (2.0) of this file was just released. 
Most of the file remained the same but the new (2.0) version has a few modifications (some lines removed, others added).

I now wish to **update** the file (1.0) to the new version (2.0), but do not wish to download the whole file again.
I would love to just patch the file with the changes of the new file, thus saving bandwith from downloading the WHOLE new file from my server.
(Similar to the way versioning systems like git or svn act)

How can I do this programmatically? Are there any iOS libraries available?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement some kind of [Binary delta compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_delta_compression) such as [zdelta](http://cis.poly.edu/zdelta/), or [Remote Differential Compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Differential_Compression) such as the one in [rsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync).

Personally I'm not aware of such algorithm implemented specifically for iOS, but I'm sure it's possible to find one that is implemented in C/C++ which can be seamlessly used in the iOS environment.

Edit: I also recommend you to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484470/is-it-possible-to-use-rsync-inside-of-ios-app).

Comment: Your link was a good read. The thing is I also want something that works well on iOS because mobile phones are not as fast as desktops. I did hope there was a good library for mobile device "diff/patching" which I was not aware of.

Comment: I'm not aware of such library, but if you're looking for a library specifically tailored for ARM processors (specifically, a library optimized using NEON), I'm quite skeptic you'll find one. I also suggest you to avoid premature optimization: try to compile one of the libraries and run them on a low-end device you want to support, then see if it meets your requirements or needs optimizations (and then, profile and optimize only the major hotspots).

Answer (score 0):

It's actually a big problem... if your API let you ask the data of a file in a specific range, you can just a ask the data range that you need to replace, and seek the file at the range and overwrite the specific data... this mean that you have to take trace about the changes every time you update the files... and your app update has to know the ranges to request... this is not a solution... I hope will be a start point to implement your own solution

to try to get partial conent in a range you need to add to your request header something like this:

```
Range: bytes=0-999
```

Comment: That would work if it was just data, but in my case its maps files I will be downloading. So I'm afraid that wouldn't work in my case.

Comment: what kind of format? it's a private one or something like an xml that define the contours? I worked 3 years with maps in iOS... maybe I can help

Comment: Its a binary file. I think the format is private but you can take a look at it if you want. --> [ctm1 format](http://www.cartotype.com/cartotypes-native-map-data-format-ctm1.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can do this by yourself without third party libraries. To achieve this, all you need is 1)Piece of code which will generate the metadata for joining versions of your file (offsets, lengths, and pointers to the data to be changed in older version); 2)piece of code which will do the hard work: read meta and put the parts on right places. Several days of struggling with offsets, and you are done ;) Good luck!

Comment: I don't trust myself on building such a library plus making it fast enough to work on mobile devices just yet.. :) Thank you for the proposal though..